# Ebay php api Finding API: Finding Items by Keywords (Does not parse the php code correctly and return data)

Tags: php, html, xml, ebay-api

So I'm fairly new to web development and I'm running PHP & HTML code that constructs an eBay Finding API endpoint and then parses through the returned XML data and displays it on the webpage.

However, when the code is run on the webserver, it does not appear to run the PHP code correctly and displays a block of the PHP code as if the code is not encapsulated correctly.
see image below
[image: this is a screenshot] .

I have the latest version of PHP (7.2.24) installed on the webserver. Also you should know that the code being run is standard as posted to the eBay tutorial webpage >> https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/HowTo/GettingStarted_PHP_NV_XML/GettingStarted_PHP_NV_XML.html <<. The only thing I've added in is my App Key.

Thanking everybody in advance for the help and assistance.

Please see code below and xml response (not filtered) >>

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);  // Turn on all errors, warnings and notices for easier debugging

// API request variables
$endpoint = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1';  // URL to call
$version = '1.0.0';  // API version supported by your application
$appid = 'MyAppID';  // Replace with your own AppID
$globalid = 'EBAY-US';  // Global ID of the eBay site you want to search (e.g., EBAY-DE)
$query = 'harry potter';  // You may want to supply your own query
$safequery = urlencode($query);  // Make the query URL-friendly
$i = '0';  // Initialize the item filter index to 0

// Create a PHP array of the item filters you want to use in your request
$filterarray =
  array(
    array(
    'name' => 'MaxPrice',
    'value' => '25',
    'paramName' => 'Currency',
    'paramValue' => 'USD'),
    array(
    'name' => 'FreeShippingOnly',
    'value' => 'true',
    'paramName' => '',
    'paramValue' => ''),
    array(
    'name' => 'ListingType',
    'value' => array('AuctionWithBIN','FixedPrice','StoreInventory'),
    'paramName' => '',
    'paramValue' => ''),
  );

// Generates an indexed URL snippet from the array of item filters
function buildURLArray ($filterarray) {
  global $urlfilter;
  global $i;
  // Iterate through each filter in the array
  foreach($filterarray as $itemfilter) {
    // Iterate through each key in the filter
    foreach ($itemfilter as $key =>$value) {
      if(is_array($value)) {
        foreach($value as $j => $content) { // Index the key for each value
          $urlfilter .= "&itemFilter($i).$key($j)=$content";
        }
      }
      else {
        if($value != "") {
          $urlfilter .= "&itemFilter($i).$key=$value";
        }
      }
    }
    $i++;
  }
  return "$urlfilter";
} // End of buildURLArray function

// Build the indexed item filter URL snippet
buildURLArray($filterarray);

// Construct the findItemsByKeywords HTTP GET call 
$apicall = "$endpoint?";
$apicall .= "OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords";
$apicall .= "&SERVICE-VERSION=$version";
$apicall .= "&SECURITY-APPNAME=$appid";
$apicall .= "&GLOBAL-ID=$globalid";
$apicall .= "&keywords=$safequery";
$apicall .= "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=3";
$apicall .= "$urlfilter";

// Load the call and capture the document returned by eBay API
$resp = simplexml_load_file($apicall);

// Check to see if the request was successful, else print an error
if ($resp->ack == "Success") {
  $results = '';
  // If the response was loaded, parse it and build links  
  foreach($resp->searchResult->item as $item) {
    $pic   = $item->galleryURL;
    $link  = $item->viewItemURL;
    $title = $item->title;
  
    // For each SearchResultItem node, build a link and append it to $results
    $results .= "<tr><td><img src=\"$pic\"></td><td><a href=\"$link\">$title</a></td></tr>";
  }
}
// If the response does not indicate 'Success,' print an error
else {
  $results  = "<h3>Oops! The request was not successful. Make sure you are using a valid ";
  $results .= "AppID for the Production environment.</h3>";
}
?>

<!-- Build the HTML page with values from the call response -->
<html>
<head>
<title>eBay Search Results for <?php echo $query; ?></title>
<style type="text/css">body { font-family: arial,sans-serif;} </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>eBay Search Results for <?php echo $query; ?></h1>

<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <?php echo $results;?>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>

Unfiltered XML Response :

<findItemsByKeywordsResponse xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">
<ack>Success</ack>
<version>1.13.0</version>
<timestamp>2020-07-01T11:59:55.672Z</timestamp>
<searchResult count="3">
<item>
<itemId>132883277485</itemId>
<title>New 11 PCS Harry Potter Hermione Dumbledore Snape Magic Wands With Box Halloween</title>
<globalId>EBAY-US</globalId>
<primaryCategory>
<categoryId>29798</categoryId>
<categoryName>Harry Potter</categoryName>
</primaryCategory>
<galleryURL>https://thumbs2.ebaystatic.com/m/mGEN-wda2-6FLyzPvzzrqSQ/140.jpg</galleryURL>
<viewItemURL>https://www.ebay.com/itm/New-11-PCS-Harry-Potter-Hermione-Dumbledore-Snape-Magic-Wands-Box-Halloween-/132883277485</viewItemURL>
<paymentMethod>PayPal</paymentMethod>
<autoPay>false</autoPay>
<postalCode>941**</postalCode>
<location>San Francisco,CA,USA</location>
<country>US</country>
<shippingInfo>
<shippingServiceCost currencyId="USD">0.0</shippingServiceCost>
<shippingType>Free</shippingType>
<shipToLocations>Worldwide</shipToLocations>
<expeditedShipping>true</expeditedShipping>
<oneDayShippingAvailable>true</oneDayShippingAvailable>
<handlingTime>1</handlingTime>
</shippingInfo>
<sellingStatus>
<currentPrice currencyId="USD">18.88</currentPrice>
<convertedCurrentPrice currencyId="USD">18.88</convertedCurrentPrice>
<sellingState>Active</sellingState>
<timeLeft>P8DT10H47M4S</timeLeft>
</sellingStatus>
<listingInfo>
<bestOfferEnabled>false</bestOfferEnabled>
<buyItNowAvailable>false</buyItNowAvailable>
<startTime>2018-12-09T22:46:59.000Z</startTime>
<endTime>2020-07-09T22:46:59.000Z</endTime>
<listingType>StoreInventory</listingType>
<gift>false</gift>
<watchCount>1654</watchCount>
</listingInfo>
<returnsAccepted>true</returnsAccepted>
<condition>
<conditionId>1000</conditionId>
<conditionDisplayName>New</conditionDisplayName>
</condition>
<isMultiVariationListing>false</isMultiVariationListing>
<topRatedListing>false</topRatedListing>
</item>
<item>
<itemId>222651343199</itemId>
<title>Harry Potter Gold Time Turner Hermione Granger Rotating Hourglass Necklace NICE!</title>
<globalId>EBAY-US</globalId>
<primaryCategory>
<categoryId>29798</categoryId>
<categoryName>Harry Potter</categoryName>
</primaryCategory>
<galleryURL>https://thumbs4.ebaystatic.com/m/mOFjLk7zQVw2PV6b3qeFY0Q/140.jpg</galleryURL>
<viewItemURL>https://www.ebay.com/itm/Harry-Potter-Gold-Time-Turner-Hermione-Granger-Rotating-Hourglass-Necklace-NICE-/222651343199</viewItemURL>
<paymentMethod>PayPal</paymentMethod>
<autoPay>true</autoPay>
<postalCode>228**</postalCode>
<location>Harrisonburg,VA,USA</location>
<country>US</country>
<shippingInfo>
<shippingServiceCost currencyId="USD">0.0</shippingServiceCost>
<shippingType>Free</shippingType>
<shipToLocations>Worldwide</shipToLocations>
<expeditedShipping>false</expeditedShipping>
<oneDayShippingAvailable>false</oneDayShippingAvailable>
<handlingTime>1</handlingTime>
</shippingInfo>
<sellingStatus>
<currentPrice currencyId="USD">7.89</currentPrice>
<convertedCurrentPrice currencyId="USD">7.89</convertedCurrentPrice>
<sellingState>Active</sellingState>
<timeLeft>P19DT1H10M28S</timeLeft>
</sellingStatus>
<listingInfo>
<bestOfferEnabled>false</bestOfferEnabled>
<buyItNowAvailable>false</buyItNowAvailable>
<startTime>2017-09-20T13:10:23.000Z</startTime>
<endTime>2020-07-20T13:10:23.000Z</endTime>
<listingType>StoreInventory</listingType>
<gift>false</gift>
<watchCount>712</watchCount>
</listingInfo>
<returnsAccepted>true</returnsAccepted>
<condition>
<conditionId>1000</conditionId>
<conditionDisplayName>New</conditionDisplayName>
</condition>
<isMultiVariationListing>false</isMultiVariationListing>
<topRatedListing>false</topRatedListing>
</item>
<item>
<itemId>362222826329</itemId>
<title>The Marauder's Map Hogwarts School of Witchcraft & Wizardry - Harry Potter, NEW!</title>
<globalId>EBAY-US</globalId>
<subtitle>Limited Edition - Direct from Warner Brothers Studios</subtitle>
<primaryCategory>
<categoryId>29798</categoryId>
<categoryName>Harry Potter</categoryName>
</primaryCategory>
<galleryURL>https://thumbs2.ebaystatic.com/m/my_kEqzf9tDxvHeJOYTg8Qg/140.jpg</galleryURL>
<viewItemURL>https://www.ebay.com/itm/Marauders-Map-Hogwarts-School-Witchcraft-Wizardry-Harry-Potter-NEW-/362222826329</viewItemURL>
<paymentMethod>PayPal</paymentMethod>
<autoPay>true</autoPay>
<postalCode>115**</postalCode>
<location>Glen Cove,NY,USA</location>
<country>US</country>
<shippingInfo>
<shippingServiceCost currencyId="USD">0.0</shippingServiceCost>
<shippingType>Free</shippingType>
<shipToLocations>Worldwide</shipToLocations>
<expeditedShipping>false</expeditedShipping>
<oneDayShippingAvailable>false</oneDayShippingAvailable>
<handlingTime>1</handlingTime>
</shippingInfo>
<sellingStatus>
<currentPrice currencyId="USD">7.99</currentPrice>
<convertedCurrentPrice currencyId="USD">7.99</convertedCurrentPrice>
<sellingState>Active</sellingState>
<timeLeft>P23DT8H21M12S</timeLeft>
</sellingStatus>
<listingInfo>
<bestOfferEnabled>false</bestOfferEnabled>
<buyItNowAvailable>false</buyItNowAvailable>
<startTime>2018-01-24T20:21:07.000Z</startTime>
<endTime>2020-07-24T20:21:07.000Z</endTime>
<listingType>StoreInventory</listingType>
<gift>false</gift>
<watchCount>2104</watchCount>
</listingInfo>
<returnsAccepted>true</returnsAccepted>
<galleryPlusPictureURL>https://galleryplus.ebayimg.com/ws/web/362222826329_1_2_1.jpg</galleryPlusPictureURL>
<condition>
<conditionId>1000</conditionId>
<conditionDisplayName>New</conditionDisplayName>
</condition>
<isMultiVariationListing>false</isMultiVariationListing>
<topRatedListing>false</topRatedListing>
</item>
</searchResult>
<paginationOutput>
<pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
<entriesPerPage>3</entriesPerPage>
<totalPages>180767</totalPages>
<totalEntries>542300</totalEntries>
</paginationOutput>
<itemSearchURL>https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=harry+potter&_ddo=1&_ipg=3&_pgn=1</itemSearchURL>
</findItemsByKeywordsResponse>
try{(function() {if (typeof(lpcurruser) == 'undefined') lpcurruser = ''; if (document.getElementById('lpcurruserelt') && document.getElementById('lpcurruserelt').value != '') { lpcurruser = document.getElementById('lpcurruserelt').value; document.getElementById('lpcurruserelt').value = ''; } if (typeof(lpcurrpass) == 'undefined') lpcurrpass=''; if (document.getElementById('lpcurrpasselt') && document.getElementById('lpcurrpasselt').value != '') { lpcurrpass = document.getElementById('lpcurrpasselt').value; document.getElementById('lpcurrpasselt').value = ''; } var lploc=1;var lponlyfill=1;(function() { var doc = document; var frm = doc.getElementById('SignInForm'); var old_username = doc.getElementById('userid'); var old_password = doc.getElementById('pass'); var runids = doc.getElementsByName('runId2'); var runid = null; if (runids.length==1) { runid = doc.getElementsByName('runId2')[0]; } if (frm && runid && old_username && old_password ) { try { old_username.value = ""; old_password.value = ""; old_username.parentNode.nextSibling.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = lpcurruser; old_password.parentNode.previousSibling.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = lpcurrpass; } catch (e) { }; } })();lpcurruser = ''; lpcurrpass = '';})();}catch(e){}try{(function() {if (typeof(lpcurruser) == 'undefined') lpcurruser = ''; if (document.getElementById('lpcurruserelt') && document.getElementById('lpcurruserelt').value != '') { lpcurruser = document.getElementById('lpcurruserelt').value; document.getElementById('lpcurruserelt').value = ''; } if (typeof(lpcurrpass) == 'undefined') lpcurrpass=''; if (document.getElementById('lpcurrpasselt') && document.getElementById('lpcurrpasselt').value != '') { lpcurrpass = document.getElementById('lpcurrpasselt').value; document.getElementById('lpcurrpasselt').value = ''; } var lploc=2;var lponlyfill=1;(function() { var doc = document; var frm = doc.getElementById('SignInForm'); var old_username = doc.getElementById('userid'); var old_password = doc.getElementById('pass'); var runids = doc.getElementsByName('runId2'); var runid = null; if (runids.length==1) { runid = doc.getElementsByName('runId2')[0]; } if (frm && runid && old_username && old_password ) { try { old_username.value = ""; old_password.value = ""; old_username.parentNode.nextSibling.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = lpcurruser; old_password.parentNode.previousSibling.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = lpcurrpass; } catch (e) { }; } })();lpcurruser = ''; lpcurrpass = '';})();}catch(e){}
```

Comment: It's easy to see where the problem is.... before ack == "Success"....  There must be something in the simplexml_load_file function that is ending php.   Which I am sure you already are aware of.  You just need to see what it is, and decide on course of action.  Try to get the full string for $apicall,  and visually inspect the xml.... then create some unit tests from that.    If you can add the xml here, it will help illicit an official answer.

Comment: @steven-matison Thank you for that. I require some clarification with regards to the ending PHP tag which is present after the PHP code before the HTML block begins. Is that not where it should be put? Please clarify

I've also added the unfiltered XML response. Part of the PHP code is to get it filtered and so I am not sure if the error might be there somewhere. Im at a loss.

Comment: Look at the bottom of the xml after </findItemsByKeywords Response>. What is that?  Is that in the xml or is it just a mistake in adding it to the post?

Comment: The php code looks right,  im confident the issue is in the simple xml line.  Also, echo the $apiurl and make sure it looks right and actually works...visit it in your browser for example.

Answer (score 0):

As it says you need to parse the result and add your HTML wrapper around the response returned. Intermittently you may notice error in response which is normal and happens due to bad response from ebay (not your fault).

```
$endpoint = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1';  // URL to call
    $version = '1.0.0';  // API version supported by your application

    $appid = 'XXXX';

    $globalid = 'EBAY-US';  // Global ID of the eBay site you want to search (e.g., EBAY-DE)
    $query = $searchkey;  // You may want to supply your own query
    $safequery = urlencode($query);  // Make the query URL-friendly

    $filterarray = array(
        array(
            'name' => 'MaxPrice',
            'value' => $maxprice,
            'paramName' => 'Currency',
            'paramValue' => 'USD'),
        array(
            'name' => 'MinPrice',
            'value' => $minprice,
            'paramName' => 'Currency',
            'paramValue' => 'USD'),
        array(
            'name' => 'Condition',
            'value' => $condition,
            'paramName' => '',
            'paramValue' => ''),
    );

    $urlfilter = "";

    function buildURLArray($filterarray)
    {
        global $urlfilter;
        $i = '0';

        // Iterate through each filter in the array
        foreach ($filterarray as $itemfilter) {
            // Iterate through each key in the filter
            foreach ($itemfilter as $key => $value) {
                if (is_array($value)) {
                    foreach ($value as $j => $content) { // Index the key for each value
                        $urlfilter .= "&itemFilter($i).$key($j)=$content";
                    }
                } else {
                    if ($value != "") {
                        $urlfilter .= "&itemFilter($i).$key=$value";
                    }
                }
            }
            $i++;
        }

        return $urlfilter;
    } // End of buildURLArray function

    $urlfilter = buildURLArray($filterarray);

    // Construct the findItemsByKeywords HTTP GET call
    $apicall = "$endpoint?";
    $apicall .= "OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords";
    $apicall .= "&SERVICE-VERSION=$version";
    $apicall .= "&SECURITY-APPNAME=$appid";
    $apicall .= "&GLOBAL-ID=$globalid";
    $apicall .= "&keywords=$safequery";
    $apicall .= "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=" . $itemcount;
    $apicall .= "$urlfilter";
    // Load the call and capture the document returned by eBay API
    $resp = simplexml_load_file($apicall);
    ?>

    <?php

    // Check to see if the request was successful, else print an error
    if ($resp->ack == "Success") {
        ?>
        <style>
            @media (min-width: 320px) {
                .eb-item-container {
                    grid-template-columns:repeat(<?php echo $itemsinrowmobile; ?>, minmax(0, 1fr));
                }
            }

            @media (min-width: 768px) {
                .eb-item-container {
                    grid-template-columns:repeat(<?php echo $itemsinrowtablet; ?>, minmax(0, 1fr));
                }
            }

            @media (min-width: 1200px) {
                .eb-item-container {
                    grid-template-columns:repeat(<?php echo $itemsinrowdesktop; ?>, minmax(0, 1fr));
                }
            }

        </style>

        <div class="eb-item-container">
            <?php
            // If the response was loaded, parse it and build links
            foreach ($resp->searchResult->item as $item) {

                foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
//                var_dump($key);
//                var_dump($value);
//                echo "<br>";
                }

                $listingtype = $item->listingInfo->listingType;
                $image = $item->galleryURL;
                $title = $item->title;
                $price = $item->sellingStatus->currentPrice;
                $shipping = $item->shippingInfo->shippingType;
                $returns = $item->returnsAccepted;
                $affiliatelink = $item->viewItemURL;
                $storename = "";
                $timeleft = $item->sellingStatus->timeLeft;
                $bidcount = "";

                ?>

                <div class="eb-item">
                    <div class="eb-buy-it">
                        <?php echo $listingtype; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="eb-thumb">
                        <a rel="noopener noreferrer nofollow" href="<?php echo $affiliatelink; ?>" target="_blank">
                            <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>"/>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="eb-title">
                        <?php echo $title; ?>
                    </h3>
                    <div class="eb-bid-container">
                        <div class="eb-price">
                            <?php echo '$' . (float)$price; ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="eb-bids">
                            <?php echo $bidcount; ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="eb-timeleft">
                            <?php /*echo $timeleft; */ ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="eb-shipping">
                        <?php echo $shipping == "Free" ? "Free shipping" : $shipping; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="eb-returns">
                        <?php echo $returns == true ? "Free returns" : $returns ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="eb-see-deal">
                        <a rel="noopener noreferrer nofollow" href="<?php echo $affiliatelink; ?>" target="_blank">See
                            Deal</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="eb-store-name">
                        eBay
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php
            }
            ?>

        </div>

        <?php
    } // If the response does not indicate 'Success,' print an error
    else {
        echo "<h5 style='text-align: center;color:#777777;'>Oops! Something went wrong in loading products.</h5>";
    }

    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $content;
```